# Converting metric to imperial

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that converts metric units to imperial units

Current code:

```js
function fuelEfficiencyMetric () {
    let distanceDriven = 500; // In Kilometers //
    let fuelConsumed = 52.28; // In Liters //
    let formula = 100; // Number needed for formula //
    let metricEfficiency = ((fuelConsumed * formula) / distanceDriven);
    console.log("Your car has a fuel economy of " + metricEfficiency.toFixed(2), "liters per hundred kilometres.");
}
fuelEfficiencyMetric();
```

Now I need to create another function where I convert the distance from kilometres to miles and litres to gallons. I could just convert the actual numbers in the last function myself and then create an identical function in imperial units, but how would I approach this if say I want to create another function that just takes the same data from the Metric function and just converts the kilometres and litres to imperial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need a "base" function that computes the efficiency based on L/km. Then you'll need additional functions to convert gallons -> liters and miles -> kilometers.

To do this effectively, you'll need to pass in the data as function arguments rather than hard-coding them.

```js
function fuelEfficiency(distanceKm, fuelL) {
  let formula = 100;
  let metricEfficiency = (fuelL * formula) / distanceKm;
  console.log(
    "Your car has a fuel economy of " + metricEfficiency.toFixed(2),
    " liters per hundred kilometres."
  );
}

function gallonsToLiters(gallons) {
  return gallons * 3.79
}

function milesToKilometers(miles) {
  return miles * 1.61
}

fuelEfficiency(100, 10);
fuelEfficiency(gallonsToLiters(30), milesToKilometers(10));
```

From here, you can create as many converters as you need, as long as you convert down to L and km you'll get the answer.